# Spring constant of typical flute style champagne glass?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring, elasticity, resonance

I am a high school student doing a lab report on the relationship between height and resonance frequency of champagne glasses, using the "singing glasses" method where you rub your finger over the rim of the glass. I am aware, of [A.P French's formula](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Eh73/tgo/praktgeluid/French1983.pdf) for this experiment, however since I am unable to derive it myself, I cannot use it in this experiment, so I have to use this formula, $ω = sqrt(\frac{k}{m})$, which relies on a spring constant for champagne glass.

Comment: Can you provide a citation for French's formula?  I don't think it's well-known.

Comment: Beyond this, I'm doubtful that a wine glass can be modeled well as a single mass on a spring.  It's a complex system comprised of many particles that are oscillating in tandem, and it will have many resonant frequencies, not just one.

Comment: The formula is shown in a study by his called "In Vino veritas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

French modeled the wine glass as a vertical cylinder with radius R, height H, and wall thickness a, on top of a rigid base. The properties of the solid material, glass, are density $\rho$ and Young's modulus Y. French's formula for the resonance frequency of the wine glass is $ f_0 = c_1 c_2 \sqrt{\frac{Y}{\rho}} \frac{a}{R^2}  $, where  $ c_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} = 0.123$ and $ c_2 =  \sqrt{1+\frac{4}{3} \left (\frac{R}{H} \right)^{4}} $. For wine glasses that are higher than wide, such as your champagne glass, $H > 2R$, so $c_2 \approx 1$ within 4%.

So when comparing French's formula with your formula, $\omega=\sqrt\frac{k}{m}$, $k$ corresponds to $Y$, and $m$ corresponds to $\rho$.